# How to handle the Clients for Peer to Peer Connection at Server Side in Java

Tags: java, android, sockets

I am working on project which require peer to peer connection between multiple clients. Clients are Window and Android Applications. So far I am able to connect the Window and Android Application to the Server which accept the connection on two port one for Window and One for the Android. In this Project we require to send some file and other resources from window to android, when the android client request. I want to know whether it is a good practice to accept the connection from window on start-up and store the socket resources in Vector with Window Client Id, And when Android send the request for a particular window client then use that socket resource and connect window to android client, Or store the window IP and Port in Database, Create the connection to window when request came from Android. Which approach is better and how to achieve that. There may be 10L connection at the same time. I am developing all the three application(Android,Web and Window) in Java.

Comment: `Or store the window IP and Port in Database, Create the connection to window when request came from Android.`. You can store anything what you want in a database. But it will be of no use when you want to make a connection from your server to a windows client. First: routers will prevent that. Second: does your windows client listen with a serversocket to incoming connections? And are you suggesting that two client could connect directly in this way?

Comment: @greenapps routers will prevent that. Yes you are right. Thats why I create connection from both client to server. Server Listen at two port. Now I want to know how to connect the window client to Mobile client. In which data str. store the Window Socket Resource, So that When Mobile App request than Server retrieve the right Socket Resource from data str and connect that to the Mobile Socket, So that both can communicate to each other.

Comment: That is not possible as far as i know. Why do you think that it is possible? What kind of technic is behind all this?

Comment: @greenapps I think it is very possible. How the peer to peer chat work ?

Comment: You think that it is possible but you gave no arguments and did not tell what technic would be used. Peer to peer chat? There is nothing against peer to peer.